# Change x-axis range

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am trying to change the range of my x-axis on my plot. The code for my plot looks like this:

```
dataset.plot(x='Date', y='Amount', label='Actual')
plt.plot(z, y_pred, label='Predicted')
plt.title('Graph')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Amount')
plt.xticks(x, x, rotation='90')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

My graph:
[image]

I am trying to stop the graph up till the last point on the orange line.

I have tried using:

```
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
```

But it creates an empty plot instead. Thank you!

Comment: Do `xmin` and `xmax` have desired values?

Comment: yes I want it to be 1-18

Comment: Have you tried `plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)`?

Comment: Yes I have, it still shows the same thing

Comment: `plt.xlim(0, 19)`. But mind that you would probably want to provide a [mcve], because possibly you have some other problem in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your plot you should be using: 'axes.set_xlim([min(z),max(z)])'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_actual = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(20, 1)), columns=['Amount'])
df_actual['Date'] = df.index

x_predicted = range(0,10)
y_predicted = np.random.uniform(0, 20, 10)

df_actual.plot(x='Date', y='Amount', label='Actual')
plt.plot(x_predicted, y_predicted, label='Predicted')

axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([min(x_predicted),max(x_predicted)])
```